# Warning: Extra attributes from the server: disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, server-side-rendering

I use `styled components` and have a button in my form which has a button.

```
const SubmitButton = styled.button`
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 5px;
`

const isSubmitDisabled = true;

return <SubmitButton disabled={isSubmitDisabled}>Save</SubmitButton>;
```

When I compile it and run via SSR setup, I see this error in browser console:

```
Warning: Extra attributes from the server: disabled
```

I searched for official docs about what attributes are "extra" and what does it mean but no luck.

Is it not allowed to pass some attributes from server? How to make my button conditionally disabled/enabled on first render?

Comment: I think this might be related to Boolean values... I've just had this issue when using a Boolean or 0/1 value. Passing string 'no' or 'yes' does not show me this error.

Comment: I think more attributes need to be added to the list here:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/993ca533b42756811731f6b7791ae06a35ee6b4d/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOMComponent.js#L954

disabled, hidden, etc....